# What does "sudo apt install" do? (no package name next to it)

Tags: command-line

Okay so, I just randomly typed in the terminal `sudo apt install` and hit enter (I was bored, okay) expecting it to tell me that I need to enter a package name to install something. After that the PC coincidentally shut off because of a power outage , so I didn't actually read what it did because I wasn't looking. Probably a dumb question but I am just curious if it actually installed anything on the system.

edit: checked logs and it didn't actually install anything.

Comment: It will do nothing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On my system, I see:

```
$ sudo apt install
[sudo] password for dkb: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
$
```

If you haven't updated your system in some time and if you have software updates pending you'll probably see the number of packages available to be updated as well as the advice to run `apt list --upgradable`.

`var/log/apt/history.log` and `/var/log/dpkg.log` and the corresponding older archived logs store information relating to packages installed or deleted by the system's package management process.

By the way,

> I just randomly typed in the terminal "sudo apt install" and hit enter (I was bored, okay)

is a little disturbing. There's nasty code out there that could damage one's system.

Further reading: https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-faq/ch-pkg_basics.en.html

Comment: Yup, I should have not done that. That was a silly mistake. Is this anything to worry about? Would I be able to remove it and would it completely be gone? I am okay with re-installing.

Comment: I don't think anything bad happened with what you asked about. I was just commenting about being careful when executing code you read about somewhere or a "friend" suggests.

Comment: Ok. It said 0 upgraded, 0 installed etc so this means it didn't actually install or write anything to the disk. Am i correct?

Comment: That's correct.